# Android studio SourceSets error: same file/folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors, source-sets

I am building 2 flavours in my project and these flavours have some code in common. This used to work good but in the latest version of android studio and gradle, I get this error.

```
SourceSets 'seta' and 'main' use the same file/folder for 'java': .../src/main/java
```

This is what I have in gradle.build

```
productFlavors {
    seta {
        packageName "com.test.seta"
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.0"
    }

    setb {
        packageName "com.test.setb"
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.6"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    seta {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/seta/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/seta/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/seta/assets']
    }

    setb {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/setb/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/setb/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/setb/assets']
    }

}
```

Comment: use flavorDimensions. works like magic!

Comment: looking for android studio flavors demo http://goo.gl/5NSnEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an individual flavor's sourceSet, you don't need to specify the main sourceSet. You can put common code in **src/main** and it will be picked up without needing to explicitly reference it from other flavors.

I'm not sure how it worked before.

If you remove that, you don't in fact need your `sourceSets` block at all -- the default behavior is to put common code in **src/main** and flavor-specific code in **src/*flavor-name***, like how you already have it set up.

Comment: does this also apply for library projects? I'm having an issue where when defining a flavor for a library project causes the main application not to pick up resources from the library project. I'm using the "canonical" directory structure.

Comment: @andreimarinescu, I'd recommend starting a new question with more details on what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Scott, I was missing the defaultPublishConfig "flavor" and publishNonDefault true statements in my library gradle file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ScottBarta Is it possible to have android project without application module folder in android studio? Here is my SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755292/can-we-have-project-without-app-folder-in-android-studio-with-everything-java-r

Comment: @ScottBarta I have removed the app folder and created folder structure like Eclipse in android studio but i stuck on building gradle as i am not getting Sync Gradle option now..