# Can we have project without app folder in android studio with everything (java/res/etc) in root

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to know that is it possible to have android project without Application module (app or any other name) in Android studio?

Means i can create package and res in root of the project itself rather than having Application Module.

**Edited :- Structure looks like**

MyApp

- .idea
- gradle
- src
- res
- assets
- AndroidManifest.xml
- build.gradle
- etc...

Answer (score 1):

Please refer "Configuring the Structure" section in https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide. You can specify a different sourceSet

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the details.. This is really helpful but i have 1 more query, how about building gradle.. how can i create build.gradle file for the project.. i just created one file and put necessary things there but its not giving me any option to sync the project. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Have you tried "Sync Project with gradle files"? Button for it is available in toolbar in android studio. Also try rebuilding project

Comment: After removing app folder and making src as my source root, i can't see any option Like Sync Gradle, Build/Clean/Rebuild in android studio. It seems that without creating module its not possible to work in android studio for android project. And once i create module it creates the structure of its own with default folders which i don't need.

Answer (score 0):

app/
   build.gradle
   src
jni
AndroidManefest.xml
build.gradle
settings.gradle

It's doable and here is how I did it:
1) Import the eclipse project from Android Studio.
   *if you have a android studio project already, skip this step.
2) Open build.gradle under sub dir app/ and copy the contents and append/paste it to build.gradle of the top level.
3) Move all files under app/ to top level.
   *if you don't have these files in top level yet.
4) Remove settings.gradle.
   * you don't need it any more since you don't have app as a submodules.
5) Added the following lines to build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
```

- Change the dir name to match your layout.
  6) "Clean Projet" and "Rebuild Project"

Note:
If you have other submodules in additional to "app", you will need keep settings.gradle and remove:
   include ":app"
from it and keep other submodules.

See my project layout here:
[image]

The final build gradle is a combination of two together:

[image]

Hope it helps.

David